# Webpack extreme slow build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I use **webpack** + **typescript** + **react**.

webpack.config.js is:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var node_modules_dir = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules');

var deps = [
  'react/react.js',
  'react-dom/react-dom.js',
];

var config = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    context: __dirname + '/Scripts/ts',
    entry: {
        server: "./server.js",
        client: "./client.ts"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "Scripts/public/"),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {},
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"],
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        noParse: [],

        // Use the expose loader to expose the minified React JS
        // distribution. For example react-router requires this
        loaders: [ {
            test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react!ts-loader'
        },
        {
            test: path.resolve(node_modules_dir, deps[0]),
            loader: "expose?React"
        },
        ]
    },
    watch: true
};

deps.forEach(function (dep) {
    var depPath = path.resolve(node_modules_dir, dep);
    config.resolve.alias[dep.split(path.sep)[0]] = depPath;
    config.module.noParse.push(depPath);
});

module.exports = config;
```

My problem is build speed. An initial process takes about 25s and incremental - 5-6 s. The result of:

```
webpack --profile --display-modules
```

is:

```
ts-loader: Using typescript@1.8.0-dev.20160104 and C:\Users\rylkov.i\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\react_test_app\react_test_app\tsconfig.json
Hash: d6d85b30dfc16f19f4a6
Version: webpack 1.12.9
Time: 25547ms
               Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    client.bundle.js  1.14 MB       0  [emitted]  client
    server.bundle.js  1.14 MB       1  [emitted]  server
client.bundle.js.map  1.31 MB       0  [emitted]  client
server.bundle.js.map  1.31 MB       1  [emitted]  server
   [0] ./client.ts 80 bytes {0} [built]
       factory:38ms building:21905ms dependencies:1ms = 21944ms
   [0] ./server.js 70 bytes {1} [built]
       factory:14ms building:19ms = 33ms
   [1] C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/~/expose-loader?Components!./components/index.js 179 bytes {0} {1} [built]
       [0] 33ms -> factory:2078ms building:8ms = 2119ms
   [2] C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/Scripts/ts/components/index.js 210 bytes {0} {1} [built]
       [0] 33ms -> [1] 2086ms -> factory:19832ms building:4ms = 21955ms
   [3] C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/Scripts/ts/components/main.tsx 4.78 kB {0} {1} [built]
       [0] 33ms -> [1] 2086ms -> [2] 19836ms -> factory:26ms building:331ms dependencies:1ms = 22313ms
   [4] C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/~/react/react.js 172 bytes {0} {1} [built]
       [0] 33ms -> [1] 2086ms -> [2] 19836ms -> [3] 357ms -> factory:315ms building:0ms = 22627ms
   [5] C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/~/react/react.js 641 kB {0} {1} [built]
       [0] 33ms -> [1] 2086ms -> [2] 19836ms -> [3] 357ms -> [4] 315ms -> factory:1ms building:86ms = 22714ms
   [6] C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/Scripts/ts/components/todoItem.tsx 2.81 kB {0} {1} [built]
       [0] 33ms -> [1] 2086ms -> [2] 19836ms -> factory:28ms building:576ms dependencies:70ms = 22629ms
   [7] C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/Scripts/ts/components/selectControl.tsx 3.44 kB {0} {1} [built]
       [0] 33ms -> [1] 2086ms -> [2] 19836ms -> factory:27ms building:428ms dependencies:218ms = 22628ms
   [8] C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/~/react-dom/react-dom.js 1.17 kB {0} {1} [built]
       [0] 33ms -> [1] 2086ms -> [2] 19836ms -> [7] 455ms -> factory:215ms building:4ms = 22629ms
   [9] C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/Scripts/ts/components/selectItem.tsx 2.63 kB {0} {1} [built]
       [0] 33ms -> [1] 2086ms -> [2] 19836ms -> factory:28ms building:502ms dependencies:144ms = 22629ms
  [10] C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/~/imports-loader?$=jquery!C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/Scripts/ui-select.js 99.6 kB {0} {1} [built]
       [0] 33ms -> [1] 2086ms -> [2] 19836ms -> [7] 455ms -> factory:150ms building:145ms = 22705ms
  [11] C:/Users/rylkov.i/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/react_test_app/react_test_app/~/jquery/dist/jquery.js 348 kB {0} {1} [built]
       [0] 33ms -> [1] 2086ms -> [2] 19836ms -> [7] 455ms -> [10] 295ms -> factory:10ms building:211ms = 22926ms
```

I think that this is extremely slow. react.js and react-dom.js are already compiled js files without extra require. My components are simply examples. 
One more problem with webpack is:

```
watch:true
```

attribute of config. I can't understand why is works **not** always. But maybe this is because slow build process. Thanks!

Comment: You tried use [CommonsChunkPlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin)?

Comment: Are you talking about Explicit vendor chunk ?

Comment: Yes exactly use a vendor to all your vendors. The first build will be the same but the next only go to reprocess your code

Comment: also, have you tried different devtool options? https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool

Comment: Having the same problem here :s

Comment: Having the same problem, using `devtool: 'eval'` did not solve it.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Well, this is the normal speed I'm afraid :(  Using both babel and typescript doubles the build time. Can't you just use ts-loader ?

Comment: @AlexG Hmm, what's weird is that in my local PC (Windows) it works fast, then in the testing server (Debian) it takes a looong time.

Comment: Maybe the testing server runs a npm install everytime? Maybe it runs a complete build (with minification, etc) whereas you just run a dev build on your machine?

Comment: I've recently experienced that "watch" doesn't work when you have something selected in the console (like accidentally clicked in the cmd window). Might be the problem.

Comment: If you press any key on your keyboard it resumes the watch process.

Answer (score 7):

One thing, specifically in development, make sure to set the `mode`:

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: "development"

  // Other options...
}
```

If not set at all (looks like it's not in the shared webpack config), it will [default to `"production"`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/). This is ideal since you'll want your code ran in production mode for deploying because it minifies, does dead code elimination, some packages (eg: React) ship different builds depending on the environment, among other things.

However, if you're in development, running in production mode can add some build time cost because doing this minification, dead code elimination, etc. add to the overall build time. This is unavoidable for the actual production built so this won't help that build time, but assuming you're building significantly more in development it should save some time.

Additionally, consider changing the [`devtool`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) option to a cheaper option such as `cheap-module-eval-source-map` or one of the other options in the docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/. The docs explain the differences and build time costs. The current option `source-map` is one of the slowest options.

```js
module.exports = {
  devtool: "eval-cheap-module-source-map"

  // Other options...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Removing `dev-tool: source-maps` should speed up the compilation time. Also it's important to note that your files are on the larger side as the output is over 1mb.

You could also add the `cacheDirectory: true` flag to babel-loader. I found that this **greatly sped up** my builds at my company. Reference - https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#options

Also I personally use the `--watch` flag for when I want webpack to run in watch mode. This lets me have more control over when I want it to actually run.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
 devtool: 'eval',
```

It will produce a considerably larger file but in half the time. Not recomended for production.

Answer (score 0):

I add **cache** to webpack config:

```
  {
  ...
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval',
  cache: true,
  ...
  }
```

before:
compiled successfully in **841 ms**

after:
compiled successfully in **61 ms**